# Adding to the results of a query on a database

Tags: c#

I am querieng a database that returns me a table with the results of the query in 3 columns. This query is run multiple times and the datatable has more results added to the previous ones each time the query is run and its results are added to the end of the existing datatable. My problem is that i have an additional 2 columns of information i want to add to to the 3 columns returned by the query each time it is run. This info comes from a string. So for example, i run the query and it returns this datatable:

```
Part No.      Color     Price
1234          Blue      12.50
5678          Red       13.25
```

Now i want to add two additional columns called Name and Damaged so the final result after the query is run will be:

```
Part No.      Color     Price     Name     Damaged
1234          Blue      12.50     Kite       No
5678          Red       13.25     Knife      Yes
```

The next time the query is run, all 5 columns should be in the datatable and the query should all info the the first three. Then i should be able to add the name and damaged info alongside the query result. How can i get this to work?

Comment: Where are you getting the data from for the other 2 columns?

Comment: What method are you using to retrieve the data from the database?

Comment: im using an oledb connection and the other data just comes from strings

Comment: What do you mean by "comes from strings"?  strings are a data type not a data source.  What strings, where do these strings come from? How are they related to the records returned from the database?  What would you logic be for matching up these "strings" to the rows in your data set?

Comment: I am working with an object that has the properties partno, color, price, name and damaged. I create an object, query database to get the first three information fields, display these to the user,then ask user to input name and damaged for each result and store the user response as strings. All 5 of this info gets put in a datatable and displayed to the user as a datagridview.

Comment: @Ryan, it's getting bit confusing; are you saying that you want to add those 3 rows (with added 2 new columns) permanently to your database OR only for your programe run (in a datatable)?

Comment: database is only for querying. I am querying the database, adding to the datatable that keeps a dynamic record of all query results. I want to add 2 columns to each result and store it as two addtional columns in the datatable each time the query is run and returns 3 rows in the datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use temporary datatable with 5 columns, keep the latest rows retrieved in that and then according to user input update temporary table and then user dt.Merge() and merge this temporary table with original table that has rows previously added.

Comment: There are more rows in the table before that i dont want to add the new information to though. I only want to add the new information to the new rows added to the table by the query i just made. For example, there are 5 rows in the table already, i do a query and it adds 3 more rows as the result. Now i want to add info about the name and damaged columns to ONLY the 3 rows that were just added to the table as the result of the query

Comment: this is not what he is asking for.

Comment: How does this merge work exactly? can i have a new table created during each query and then when i have added the extra column and their info, merge it to a global variable datatable?